# MySQL select string

Tags: mysql

when returning this string of code I don't get the 12 rows like i'm suppose to and idk why, what did I do wrong, there is 12 rows that show up when no percentage is added.

```
SELECT invoice_due_date, invoice_total,SUM(invoice_total)    
       * .10 / invoice_total,SUM(invoice_total)    
       * .20 / invoice_total
FROM invoices
# ROWS: 12
WHERE invoice_total >= 500 OR invoice_total <= 10000
ORDER BY invoice_due_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only one row, because you're using an aggregate function without a `group by`. Therefore it sums all rows of invoice_total column.

I guess, what you want to do is this:

```
SELECT 
invoice_due_date, 
invoice_total, 
sum_invoice_total * .10 / invoice_total, 
sum_invoice_total * .20 / invoice_total
FROM invoices
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(invoice_total) FROM invoices WHERE invoice_total >= 500 OR invoice_total <= 10000) sum_invoice_total
WHERE invoice_total >= 500 OR invoice_total <= 10000
ORDER BY invoice_due_date DESC
```

Comment: @KenaAlysPechacek Updated my answer with what I think you want to do :)